# react dynamic import does not work when using module name as variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have been trying to dynamically import a css file in my react component as follows:

```
componentWillMount () {
    import(this.props.theme) // this.props.theme = "path/to/css"
}
```

but it does not work, the weird part is that, when I hardcode the css file, it works!

```
componentWillMount () {
    import("path/to/css");
}
```

Any ideas?

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module 'path/to/css'.
(anonymous function)
C:/app/myComponent lazy:5
```

**EDITED, RESOLVED:**

I needed to import a css file in this location: "../path/to/theme.css"
I removed the "../" from the props and concatenated it in the import statement

```
import(`../${this.state.theme}`)
```

Comment: what error do you get??

Comment: Try `import(\`${this.props.theme}\`)`

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu. I edited the question.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I've got the same error. C:/app/myComponent lazy /^.*$:24

Comment: you need to set relative path

Comment: Why don't you just lazy load the whole component and include the CSS as normal?